# question involving extracting row values rather than row numbers in outlier analysis

Tags: r, database, dataframe, outliers

I am running an outlier analysis using the Routliers package. Here is sample data, an abridged version.

```
id   v1  v2
24   1   4  
2    2   5  
18   3   6
```

The outlier package will print out the rows. See sample code.

```
library(Routliers)
CR_metrics_1 <- CR_metrics[c(1,2,3)]
res <- outliers_mcd(x = data.frame(CR_metrics_1[-1]), h = .75, alpha = .05)
res$outliers_out ##prints out rows
```

This is what is outputted:

```
res$outliers_out 
1 3
```

However, I want the specific ids that are a problem, in this case 24 and 18.

I tried creating a vector and df with the thought of somehow being able to extract the ids that are a problem. To be clear, I would like a df that has the ids that are a problem, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
x <- res$outliers_out

cbind.fill <- function(...){
  nm <- list(...) 
  nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
  n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
  do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
    rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}

a <- cbind.fill(df)
```

Does anyone have any advice about how to this?

Comment: What would be wrong with `df[res$outliers_out, "id"]`?

Comment: Thank you @coffeinjunky. I am getting the following error message when I use that code: Error in df[res$outliers_pos, "id"] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Are you working with a data frame?

Comment: Actually, that worked! I realized I used a vector where df should be. Thank you so much!! :)